# can I upload an App developed in GWT framework (Eclipse IDE) to local servers?

Tags: cloud

For Google App Engine service can't be accessed from China Mainland, so I plan to upload the App into local servers, can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

If you are unable to use Google App Engine Service, there are lot many alternatives as well.
Like you can try with Jelastic.
http://jelastic.com/docs

try the trial and I guess that might help you .

Answer (score 0):

To add to Bunta's answer, here are specific instructions on deploying GWT to Jelastic: http://jelastic.com/docs/google-web-toolkit

Jelastic is probably also the best choice for you because it is available in 10+ countries around the world (you can select the local hoster when you sign-up at http://jelastic.com right below the sign-up form) - so if one happens to be not accessible in your country - you can pick another.